# Memory Allocator implementation segfault

Tags: c

I am currently developing a memory allocator, I have come with this code a the moment but this code below segfault on almost every commands when i do a LD_PRELOAD of my implementation.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include "malloc.h"

t_mem_map       g_map;
int         g_empty_map = TRUE;

static t_ctrl       *get_free_block(size_t size)
{
  t_ctrl        *tmp;

  tmp = g_map.head;
  while (tmp != NULL)
    {
      if (tmp->is_free == TRUE && tmp->size < size)
    {
      tmp->is_free = FALSE;
      return (tmp);
    }
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }
  return (NULL);
}

static void     *init_map(size_t size)
{
  t_ctrl        *tmp;

  g_map.map_size = DEFAULT_MAP_SIZE;
  while (g_map.map_size < size + sizeof(t_ctrl))
    g_map.map_size += DEFAULT_MAP_SIZE;
  if ((g_map.head = (t_ctrl *)sbrk(g_map.map_size)) == (void *)-1)
    return (NULL);
  tmp = g_map.head;
  tmp->next = NULL;
  tmp->prev = NULL;
  tmp->size = size;
  tmp->is_free = FALSE;
  g_map.free_space = g_map.map_size - size - sizeof(t_ctrl);
  g_empty_map = FALSE;
  unlock_thread();
  return ((void *)((char *)tmp + sizeof(t_ctrl)));
}

static void     *add_block(size_t size)
{
  t_ctrl        *tmp;
  t_ctrl        *new;

  tmp = get_free_block(size);
  if (tmp != NULL)
    return ((void *)((char *)tmp + sizeof(t_ctrl)));
  tmp = g_map.head;
  while (tmp->next != NULL)
    tmp = tmp->next;
  new = (t_ctrl *)((char *)tmp + sizeof(t_ctrl) + tmp->size);
  new->prev = tmp;
  new->next = NULL;
  tmp->next = new;
  new->size = size;
  new->is_free = FALSE;
  g_map.free_space -= (new->size + sizeof(t_ctrl));
  unlock_thread();
  return ((void *)((char *)new + sizeof(t_ctrl)));
}

static void     *resize_map(size_t size)
{
  size_t        size_shift;

  size_shift = 0;
  while (g_map.free_space < size + sizeof(t_ctrl))
    {
      g_map.map_size += DEFAULT_MAP_SIZE;
      g_map.free_space += DEFAULT_MAP_SIZE;
      size_shift += DEFAULT_MAP_SIZE;
    }
  if (sbrk(size_shift) == (void *)-1)
    return (NULL);
  return (add_block(size));
}

void            *malloc(size_t size)
{
  size_t        a_size;

  lock_thread();
  a_size = ALIGN(size);
  if (g_empty_map == TRUE)
    return (init_map(a_size));
  else
    {
      if ((a_size + sizeof(t_ctrl)) <= g_map.free_space)
        return (add_block(a_size));
      else
    return (resize_map(a_size));
    }
  return (NULL);
}
```

Here is the malloc.h :

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stddef.h>
# include <unistd.h>

# define TRUE 0
# define FALSE 1

# define SUCCESS 0
# define FAILURE 1


# ifndef __X86_64__
#  define ALIGNMENT (16)
# else
#  define ALIGNMENT (8)
# endif

# define ALIGN(size) (((size) + (ALIGNMENT - 1)) &~ (ALIGNMENT - 1))
# define DEFAULT_MAP_SIZE (ALIGN(sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)))

typedef struct      s_ctrl
{
  size_t        is_free;
  size_t        size;
  struct s_ctrl     *next;
  struct s_ctrl     *prev;
}           t_ctrl;

typedef struct      s_mem_map
{
  size_t        map_size;
  size_t        free_space;
  //  int           free_blocks;
  //int         nb_blocks;
  t_ctrl        *head;
}           t_mem_map;
```

With some research I found out that the segfault is likely coming from the while loop in the get_free_block() function but i can't understand why.

```
static t_ctrl       *get_free_block(size_t size)
{
  t_ctrl        *tmp;

  tmp = g_map.head;
  while (tmp != NULL)
    {
      if (tmp->is_free == TRUE && tmp->size < size)
        {
          tmp->is_free = FALSE;
          return (tmp);
        }
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }
  return (NULL);
}
```

Comment: Well, did you use a debugger?  SO is not a replacement for that.

Comment: I am assuming that is an assembler opcode that the error occurs on?  Arm-ish or something else?  ALso, I would expect the debugger to stop right on the line that the bad access occurs on - does it not?

Comment: You tell us that the code segfaults on "almost every command", then give us several functions and don't tell us which one -- if any -- segfaults consistently. Try to construct a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will help everything.

Comment: For your own sanity, especially when doing something like this, please comment the heck out of your code so that everyone (including you) knows what the ideas are behind each sizeof() add and compare and...  Placing these comments into your code will more than likely lead you to your own error as you rethink things through.

Comment: @Beta: He is implementing his own allocator and gets a lot of segfaults.  The obvious (admittedly not necessarily right) conclusion is that the allocator function contains a bug and not in the functions calling it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't verify that this is the only problem, but you are checking  `tmp->size < size`, when you probably should check `tmp->size >= size` instead.

Comment: Oh my god I have check my code several times and did not see this mistake thank you.

Comment: @Epoch: Yeah, I know that feeling. Are you familiar with [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)? That helps sometimes.

Comment: No i didn't know this method, thanks for the advice.